# CTMC simulation with birth & death process using C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Math isn't my strong skill. However, I need to simulate continuous time markov chain (CTMC) transition times for birth & death process using C++.

I came across this [github project](https://github.com/NathanEpstein/markov) which simulates regular CTMC, where the row sum of all lambda will be 1. But in case of birth-death process (M/M/c/K), it will be zero. So I can't exactly use it for my purpose.

Where can I find the algorithm to simulate M/M/c/K CTMC? I can code the algorithm if I find it. But I am unable to build out the algorithm by myself, the math goes above my head.

I need this simulation to send events to a M/M/c/K queue, using poisson distribution. That way I can figure out server (c) requirement under different arrival rates (lambda), while ensuring maximum server utilization.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a M/M/c/k process, or to typify it mathematically? The former isn't too hard... just have an event queue keeping track of when a server finishes processing a job and when a new job arrives to the job queue.

Comment: I have to simulate, like in the github project CTMC example. Except mine is M/M/c/K. I have generated the transition rate matrix (row sum is zero), but I am not sure how simulate it like in that github example.

Comment: There's no overwhelming reason to think in terms of transition matrices for something like this which can be separated into simpler simultaneous processes. Just have a process for arrivals, a per-server handling process, and an event queue to synthesize them all.

Comment: I am the one who has to send the events to a queue with a poisson distribution. I am writing a program to test a M/M/c/K queue. That is the reason for simulation.

Comment: To me it is totally unclear what you really want and why the theoretical results that you could google don't work for you

Comment: I have been googling for weeks in vain. There is a M/M/c/K event queue, I need to sent events to it so that all the event handlers (c) are kept fully utilized. Obviously the events have to follow poisson distribution. If I merely use lambda (birth rate) to generate a poisson process, I might overrun the queue (>K) or underuse the handlers (<c). So I have to factor death rate (Mu) too. But I don't know how to generate a poisson process using both lambda and Mu. I don't know how else to explain.

Comment: Some things I don't understand: 1) You say 'row sum of all lambdas will be zero' could you please elaborate about this 2) What is the difference between dying and being processed by a server? Couldn't you just model it with just an additional server with a rate different from other servers?

Comment: Look at the transition rate matrix for M/M/c/K, it row sum is always zero. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue

The arrival rate (birth) is poisson distribution. But processing time is exponential. When processing ends, it is called dying.

http://blog.simul8.com/simul8-tip-difference-between-poisson-and-exponential-distributions-for-arrivals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not 100% clear what your heart's desire might be, but the topic is pretty interesting.

First: The github project you are referring to is not documented well enough to say what exactly it expects as input and I don't have enough knowledge about Markov processes to say that the continuous part is wrong, but to me it does not make much sense.

Secondly:  The sum of a row of a transition rate matrix is 0 for all Markov processes, not only for birth-death processes.

That is how I would simulate a run:

1. Given: the start state (probably `0`) `S`, transition rate matrix `Q` (defined via`P'=PQ`), number of transitions `n` of interest.
2. Output: `times` - times to which the transitions occurred, `states` - the series of visited states.

Here we go with a wild mix of C++ and pseudo-code:

```
std::default_random_engine rnd;//ini

double current_time=0.0;
int current_state=S;
vector<doubles> times={current_time};
vector<int> states={current_state};

for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
//Part 1: simulate the time staying in current state:
  double decay_rate=-Q[current_state][current_state];
  if(decay_rate==0.0){
  //that means we are not going anywhere anymore and staying for ever in this state:
      return;
  }
  //we don't do error checking and expect rate to be positive, because diagonal elements of Q must be 0.0 or negative
  //The current state will decay with the decay_rate, so the life time in this state until the decay is exponentially distributed with parameter decay_rate
 //simulate the life time:
 std::exponential_distribution<> life_time_generator(decay_rate);
 double life_time=life_time_generator(rnd);
 times.push_back(times.back()+life_time);

//Part2: to which state have we actually decayed?
// The probability to decay to the state new_state is proportional to transition rate Q[current_state][new_state]
//thus generate an uniformly distributed random variable [0, decay_rate] (decay_rate - sum of transition rates of all possible new states) and map it on the states:
 double target_value=std::generate_canonical<double,10>(rnd)*decay_rate;
 double sum=0.0;
 for (int new_state=0;new_state<Q.size();new_state++){
     if (new_state==current_state)//don't forget to skip the state itself
         continue;
     sum+=Q[current_state][new_state];
     if (sum>target_value){//we found our next state!
         current_state=new_state;
         states.push_back(current_state);
         break;
     }
     //there are still a some precision issues, if the sum of all transition rates is slightly under 1.0
     //the issues should be handled somehow but not in this pseudo-code.
 }

}
// do whatever you want with times/states
```

I hope it is something you had in mind.

**Edit:**

As short explanation:

1. For the first part - the time until the transition. The code is based on the well known fact, that if the arrivals are Poisson distributed with rate lambda, than the waiting times are exponential distributed with parameter lambda. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Memoryless_property)
2. For the second part - it is just the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability): The transition probability for a very short period of time `dt` is `-Q[current_state][current_state]dt`. This condition is fulfilled as we know the transition happened. The probability to go to the state `new_state`is `Q[current_state][new_state]*dt` but under the condition that the transition happened it is `Q[current_state][new_state]/-Q[current_state][current_state]` - and that is what is calculated in the second part.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. BTW, not all markov chain row sum is zero. Check this video: https://youtu.be/hUBc2Nb8yyI?t=633

Comment: @Sharath Can it be, that you confuse transition **rate** matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) and transition matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)?

Comment: OMG, they are different? No wonder I am getting confused repeatedly. I got out of college 26 years ago, hardly dabbled with probabilities since then. I started learning markov chains couple weeks ago to solve this problem. Thanks, let me look at it all over again.

Comment: Thanks ead, you may have cracked this one. I generated the State/TransitionTimes many times by varying the lambda and mu, and by gut feel the sequence looks realistic. Of course, I can't be sure until I send the events against the actual M/M/c/K queue. That will take a week to setup. I am finally on the right path. Can you please point out the equation you used to form this algorithm, any URL that explains this logic will do. I like to understand it so that I can tweak the code if necessary. Thank you again, I am really grateful.

Comment: @Sharath it's mostly some basic stuff, but added a little more information.

Comment: I wrote the simulator and did extensive testing. The algorithm is working is beautifully. The idea is to keep the servers at maximum utilization while ensuring there is very little time spend in the queue. So I keep varying the lambda to achieve that. If the events I send spend time in the queue, I reduce the lambda by 5%, and if the servers are under utilized, I increase the lambda by 5%. Wish I could calculate the lambda correctly for the given mu and server count, instead of trail and error.

Comment: @Sharath Take a look at the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue#Stationary_analysis_2 (if you are interested in the transient analysis, there are at least some starting point). pi_0 is the time part your servers are idle, there is also the response time formula given. Is it what you need?